# Is "belongingness" used in American English?

Tags: word-choice

Is "belongingness" used in American English? 
Ex. "the construction of social belongingness is markedly a relational process".

Comment: Those Americans who would write *"the construction of social _____ is markedly a relational process"* might actually be prone to using the word *"belongingness"*. But the rest of us don't.

Comment: I've never heard it before.  But if you drop the "ness" - "the construction of social belonging is markedly a relational process" then yes, that sounds natural.

Comment: I'd agree that 'belongingness' sounds more awkward than the gerund 'belonging', but it is still valid.

Comment: I remember *belongingness* from Maslow, but nowadays it seems to be associated primarily with something called [belongingness theory](http://persweb.wabash.edu/facstaff/hortonr/articles%20for%20class/baumeister%20and%20leary.pdf) in psychology. So yes, [it is used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=social+belongingness&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3), but I would not recommend that *you* use it except very carefully. Among social scientists, it refers to a specific concept. Among the general public, *belonging* is entirely adequate.

Comment: Only under duress, or the influence of soporific writing. :-).

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=belongingness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelongingness%3B%2Cc0) reveals that the term is remarkably common in US English since about 1940.  However, it appears that the term is mainly used in a semi-technical sense in the social sciences, and it may have a "jargon" meaning.

Answer (score 1):

***[Belongingness](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/belongingness):***

> - the quality or state of being an essential or important part of something:
>
>   - *The company has developed social programs to give employees a sense of belongingness.*

(Random House Dictionary)

The term appears to be more common than one might expect and 
according to ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=belongingness%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbelongingness%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbelongingness%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbelongingness%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)*** it is now equally common in AmE and BrE.

Comment: Though it is mostly used as psychological jargon/double talk.  It's not a word that ordinary humans would use.